# Hadoop - Formatting dates when creating tables

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, format

How to format dates during the process of creating Hive tables?

I've currently been dumping some data into a discovery environment at work and storing dates as string, because if I format them as a DATE or TIMESTAMP the values are null.

Here's what the raw data looks like:

```
12/07/2016 05:07:28 PM
```

My understanding is that Hive accepts dates in this format

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

I can format these using a select statement:

```
select id, receipt_dt, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(receipt_dt ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as app_dt from MySchema.MyTable where app_num='123456'
```

How can I add in the statement

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(receipt_dt ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

How can I add this in to the generic CREATE EXTERNAL STATEMENT below so that I no longer have to store dates as a string, or use an ALTER TABLE statement to change the formatting?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MySchema.My_New_Table 
( Field1 Format, 
Field2 Format, 
Field 3 Format, 
) 
.......
```

Comment: Storing dates as strings is a horrible idea.  If your problem is populating a date or timestamp field, focus on solving that problem.

Comment: Maybe you mis understood the question. I do NOT want to store these as a string... hence why I said I have been, but am looking to format these dates as an acceptable DATE format within HIVE in my CREATE TABLE statement so that I don't have to store as a string... again, this is DISCOVERY. I know this is a bad idea, that's kind of why I posted the question...

Comment: You would do well not to scream at people in all caps while asking for help.

Comment: Apologies. I re-read my question and it wasn't clear that what I am trying to do is not store dates as strings. I wish to store them as dates without having to alter a table after storing them as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MyTable` as staging table with raw data and create final/target table `my_new_table` with transformations i.e, `date` format...it will be EDW kind of process...

example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MySchema.My_New_Table 
( Field1 int, 
Field2 string, 
Field3 date
) 
... more definitions....
AS
select id, receipt_dt, 
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(receipt_dt ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date) as app_dt 
from MySchema.MyTable ;
```

***NOTE:*** This is not tested statement. You may need to try and edit and try...but you got the idea...

Then inserting delta should be similar process...

```
INSERT INTO TABLE MySchema.My_New_Table
AS
select id, receipt_dt, 
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(receipt_dt ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date) as app_dt 
from MySchema.MyTable  where <<conditions>>;
```

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping I wouldn't have to create two tables for this process but if it must be done, it must be done!

Comment: yes or....transform data using pig/spark/MR anyone of your choice....if you just want to create one table :) ... but yeah we can't do both (loading+transformations) that only with one hive table

Comment: Haha, I don't even know if I can access Spark at work. I'm more on the business side, we're just dumping tables into a discovery environment to see what data we actually have.

I do have a question though, if I'm creating a new table based off of an old one in the first example, what is the purpose of the second set of code?

Comment: second set? you mean insert? if so - in future if there are new data in first/old table and you want these new data available in new table with same `date` format... you can use `insert` to keep both tables in sync - so create table once and then keep them in sync with new data..with `inserts`